# A Schauder basis of Schwartz space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

It is well-known that hermite functions $\{h_n(x)\}_n$ form a Schauder basis of the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.
Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}^*$. Does the 'modified' family of functions $\{\alpha h_n(\beta x)\}_n$ still form a Schauder basis of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ ??

Comment: Did you try the automorphism on $\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$ defined by $T(f)(x)=f(x/\beta)/\alpha$?

Comment: It is so clear now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COMMUNITY WIKI: VAGUE ANSWER, USE AS A DRAFT

I vaguely remember a "dilation formula" or "linearization formula", something like that, unfortunately I forgot the exact nomenclature. It reads
$$
H_n(\beta x) =\sum_{j=0}^n a_{j, n, \beta} H_j(x),$$
for $\beta >0$. This is relevant here.

Indeed, you can forget about that $\alpha$, it is irrelevant, if a set is Schauder then $\alpha$ times that set is still Schauder. The problem is that $\beta$. The formula I vaguely remember might take care of that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was helpful.

Comment: Oh really? I'm glad to hear that, but the comment of Jochen provides a quicker answer to this problem. The linearization coefficients may be useful for something else, anyway. I have been skimming the book of Askey, "Special functions and orthogonal polynomials". The chapter called "Lecture 7" is dedicated exactly to those. But I could not locate the exact formula you need here.

Comment: Yes it is ! thank you so much for the aded suggestions, it's gonna help a lot